# Swift multipeer video app won't read data

Tags: swift, video, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to create an app that will take video from an iphone and send it to an ipad through Apple's multipeer interface.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Multipeer Video
//
//


import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity
import CoreMotion
import SceneKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController,       MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCSessionDelegate, NSStreamDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
{
//Video
let transferredSession = AVCaptureSession()
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var transferredLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
var videoDeviceOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!
var sessionQueue: dispatch_queue_t!
var data = NSData()
var movieplayer = MPMoviePlayerController()

//MultiPeer
let label = UILabel()
var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
let serviceType = "motion-control"
let peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
var serviceAdvertiser : MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!
var serviceBrowser : MCNearbyServiceBrowser!
lazy var session : MCSession =
{
    let session = MCSession(peer: self.peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: MCEncryptionPreference.Required)
    session.delegate = self
    return session
}()


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Video
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
    for device in devices {
        // Make sure this particular device supports video
        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                if captureDevice != nil {
                    print("Capture device found")

                }
            }
        }
    }

    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    view.addSubview(label)
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad
    {
        label.text = "iPad"
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        initialiseAdvertising()
        //need to setup recieving video
    }
    else
    {
        label.text = "iPhone"
        initialiseBrowsing()
        beginVideoSession()
    }

}

func beginVideoSession() {

    configureDevice()
    do {
        //try captureSession.addInput(input: captureDevice)
        try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
        updateDeviceSettings(0.0, isoValue: 0.0)
    } catch {
        //error message etc.
        print("Capture device not initialisable")
    }
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
    previewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer!, atIndex: 0)
    captureSession.startRunning()
}

func configureDevice() {
    if let device = captureDevice {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            device.focusMode = .Locked
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            //error message etc.
            print("Capture device not configurable")
        }
    }

}

// set ISO

func updateDeviceSettings(focusValue : Float, isoValue : Float) {
    if let device = captureDevice {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            device.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(focusValue, completionHandler: { (time) -> Void in
            })

            let minISO = device.activeFormat.minISO
            let maxISO = device.activeFormat.maxISO
            let clampedISO = isoValue * (maxISO - minISO) + minISO

            device.setExposureModeCustomWithDuration(AVCaptureExposureDurationCurrent, ISO: clampedISO, completionHandler: { (time) -> Void in
                //
            })

            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print("Can't update device settings")
        }

    }
}


// MARK: MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate (iPhone is browser)

var streamTargetPeer: MCPeerID?
var outputStream: NSOutputStream?

func initialiseBrowsing()
{
    serviceBrowser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: peerID, serviceType: serviceType)
    serviceBrowser.delegate = self
    serviceBrowser.startBrowsingForPeers()
}

func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?)
{
    print( "Found Peer! \(peerID)")
    streamTargetPeer = peerID
    browser.invitePeer(peerID, toSession: session, withContext: nil, timeout: 120)

    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.step))
    displayLink?.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    print("displayLink")
}

//Initializes SampleBufferDelegate and videoDeviceOutput
func addVideoOutput() {
    videoDeviceOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoDeviceOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    self.sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Camera Session", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    videoDeviceOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: sessionQueue)
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoDeviceOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(videoDeviceOutput)
    }
}

//Grabbing frames from camera
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    print("frame received")
    let imageBuffer: CVImageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)
    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)
    let src_buff = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)
    data = NSData(bytes: src_buff, length: bytesPerRow * height)
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

}

func startStream()
{
    guard let streamTargetPeer = streamTargetPeer where outputStream == nil else
    {
        return
    }
    do
    {
        print("stream started")
        outputStream =  try session.startStreamWithName("MotionControlStream", toPeer: streamTargetPeer)
        outputStream?.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        outputStream?.open()
    }
    catch
    {
        print("unable to start stream!! \(error)")
    }
}

func step()
{
    startStream()
    print("step")
    guard let outputStream = outputStream else
    {
        print("no stream")
        return
    }
    if outputStream.hasSpaceAvailable
    {
        print("writing to output")
        outputStream.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)
    }
    else
    {
        print("no space availale")
    }
}

func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID)
{
    label.text = "Lost Peer!"
}

// MARK: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate (iPad is advertiser)

func initialiseAdvertising()
{
    serviceAdvertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peerID, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: serviceType)
    serviceAdvertiser.delegate = self
    serviceAdvertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()
}

// MARK: MCSessionDelegate

func session(session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChangeState state: MCSessionState)
{
    let stateName:String
    switch state
    {
    case MCSessionState.Connected:
        stateName = "connected"
    case MCSessionState.Connecting:
        stateName = "connecting"
    case MCSessionState.NotConnected:
        stateName = "not connected"
    }

    let deviceName:String
    switch UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom
    {
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad:
        deviceName = "iPad"
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone:
        deviceName = "iPhone"
    default:
        deviceName = "Unspecified"
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
    {
        self.label.text = "\(deviceName) didChangeState: \(stateName)"
    }
}


func session(_: MCSession, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID)
{
    print("did recieve")
    stream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    stream.delegate = self
    stream.open()
}

func stream(stream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent)
{
    print(eventCode)
    if eventCode == NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered{
        print("end")
    }
    print("stream started")
    if let inputStream = stream as? NSInputStream //where eventCode == NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable
    {
        print("Does this byte?")
       /* let bufferSize = 1024
        var buffer = [UInt8](count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)
        let bytesRead = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
        print(bytesRead)
        if bytesRead >= 0 {
            let output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: bytesRead, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(output)
        }
        */

        var bytes = [UInt8](count:12, repeatedValue: 0)
        inputStream.read(&bytes, maxLength: data.length)


        let dataIn: NSData = "Stream".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!
        let stream: NSInputStream = NSInputStream(data: dataIn)
        var buffer = [UInt8](count: 8, repeatedValue: 0)
        stream.open()
        if stream.hasBytesAvailable {
            print("stream has bytes!")
            let result: Int = stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
            print("result: \(result)")

            let dataString: NSString =  NSString(data: dataIn, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print(dataString)
            let movieURL = NSURL.init(string: dataString as String)
            print(movieURL)

        } else {
        print("stream has no bytes")
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {

        }


        //*/
    }
    if let outstream = stream as? NSOutputStream {
        print("This is output")
        print(outstream)
    }
}

func session(session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, atURL localURL: NSURL, withError error: NSError?)
{
}

func session(session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withProgress progress: NSProgress)
{
}

// MARK: Layout

func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID)
{
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad
    {
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: topLayoutGuide.length, width: view.frame.width, height: label.intrinsicContentSize().height)
    }
    else
    {
        label.frame = view.bounds
    }
}

func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: NSData?, invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession) -> Void)
{
    invitationHandler(true, self.session)
}
}
```

It seems as if I'm able to send data properly with the iphone, but I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong with the iPad. I would guess it has to do with the run loop, but while troubleshooting it I've noticed that the iPad receives an end encountered eventcode.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are (obviously) two primary tasks involved: storing the base address of a pixel buffer into an NSData object, and then restoring the base address on the other end. The best way to do this with Apple's MultiPeerConnectivity framework is not by streams, but by data objects.

Here's how you send the raw buffer data from a CVPixelBuffer from your iPhone:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        NSError *err;
        [((ViewController *)self.parentViewController).session sendData:[self dataFromImageBuffer:imageBuffer withBytesPerRow:CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer) withHeight:CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)] toPeers:((ViewController *)self.parentViewController).session.connectedPeers withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:&err];
     }
}
 
- (NSData *)dataFromImageBuffer:(CVImageBufferRef)imageBuffer withBytesPerRow:(size_t)bytesPerRow withHeight:(NSInteger)height
{
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData new];
    if (CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0) == kCVReturnSuccess)
    {
        uint8_t *rawBuffer = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
        [data appendBytes:rawBuffer length:1228808];
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Here's how you display it on your iPad:

```
- (void)session:(nonnull MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(nonnull NSData *)data fromPeer:(nonnull MCPeerID *)peerID {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSMutableData *mdata = [NSMutableData new];
        UInt8 *rawBuffer = (uint8_t *)[data bytes];
        [mdata appendBytes:rawBuffer length:1228808];
        uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)[mdata bytes];
        NSLog(@"sizeof(buffer) %lu", sizeof(buffer));
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(buffer, 640, 480, 8, 2560, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
        CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
        
        CGContextRelease(newContext);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:newImage scale:1 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        CGImageRelease(newImage);
        
        if (image) {
            NSLog(@"image size %f x %f", [image size].width, [image size].height);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [((ViewerViewController *)self.childViewControllers.lastObject).view.layer setContents:(__bridge id)image.CGImage];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Mind you, this is the raw, uncompressed and otherwise unaltered image data; accordingly, it is huge, and will take too long to transfer from one device to another to make the product viable.

Here's one way to compress the data prior to sending it in order to achieve real-time performance; it is lesser in quality than the solution I use now, but it's quick and easy.

On your iPhone:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
    CGContextRelease(newContext);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:newImage scale:1 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    CGImageRelease(newImage);
    if (image) {
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7);
        NSError *err;
        [((ViewController *)self.parentViewController).session sendData:data toPeers:((ViewController *)self.parentViewController).session.connectedPeers withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:&err];
     }
```

}

On your iPad:

```
- (void)session:(nonnull MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(nonnull NSData *)data fromPeer:(nonnull MCPeerID *)peerID {
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
if (image) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Displaying image...");
        [((ViewerViewController *)self.childViewControllers.lastObject).view.layer setContents:(__bridge id)image.CGImage]; 
    });
}
}
```